# sort the keys of deep nested hash according to value?

Tags: perl

try to sort nested hash according to its values, long story,i parse `%senseHash` and store certain values in `%rankedTest` hash 
later, i want to loop through sort `%rankedTest` and output to file 
my code:

```
foreach my $str (keys %senseHash)
{
    my $selectedSense;
    if (exists $senseHash{$str}{'phone'} && exists $senseHash{$str}{'product'})
     {
        if ($senseHash{$str}{'phone'} > $senseHash{$str}{'product'})
        {
            $selectedSense='phone';
        }else
        {
            $selectedSense='product';
        }
         my $pPhone = $senseHash{$str}{'phone'} / $senses{'phone'};
         my $pProduct = $senseHash{$str}{'product'} / $senses{'product'};
         my $rankScore = abs(log($pPhone/$pProduct));
         $rankedTest{$str}{$selectedSense}=$rankScore;
     }
}
open($f1, '>', $inputs[1]);
foreach my $e (keys  %rankedTest)
{
    foreach my $s (sort { $rankedTest{$e}{$b} <=> $rankedTest{$e}{$a} } keys %{$rankedTest{$e}})
    {
        print $f2 "feature:$e -> sense:$s -> score:$rankedTest{$e}{$s} \n";
    }
}
```

but output is something as below :

```
feature:operations -> sense:product -> score:0.0859904478555225 
feature:move -> sense:product -> score:0.309133999169732 
feature:dispute -> sense:phone -> score:0.0963311089384321
```

while what i actually want is :

```
feature:move -> sense:product -> score:0.309133999169732 
feature:dispute -> sense:phone -> score:0.0963311089384321 
feature:operations -> sense:product -> score:0.0859904478555225
```

any clue what i did wrong or how i can accomplish this. any suggestion will help.

EDIT: inside hash has one key which could be phone or product and i want to sort according to what this key value regardless of the key whether `phone` or `product`

Comment: Can you give an example of how the `%rankedTest` hash look like? Do you want to sort product and phones separately? I.e. sort all phone values numerically, then sort all product values numerically.

Comment: I am also thinking about where `phone` is in the output ... is it always `<` (in the earlier selection) so it never makes it into `%rankedTest`?  If you need to sort with _one_ key in the subhash (`product`) that's one thing, but to sort the top-level keys by _two_ subkeys (both `product` and `phone`) more work is needed.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant, "sort the top-level keys by" ... values for multiple subkeys

Comment: Right, that's very different.  You'll need to "unwrap" the whole data structure.  Even if you sort by `max` of values of subkeys, still _all_ (top-level) entries from the key with the highest value come first, (probably) breaking the order of other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a multi-level hash by values in its bottom layer we have to compare *all* entries.

This code builds strings to be printed for all levels using (double) [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), then sorts that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# Example hash     
my %h = ( 
    oper => { prod => 0.8, phone => 0.03 },  
    disp => { prod => 0.2, phone => 0.05 },  
    move => { prod => 0.6, phone => 0.01 } 
); 

my @res = 
    sort { (split ":", $b)[-1] <=> (split ":", $a)[-1] }
    map { 
        my $k = $_; 
        map { "feature:$k -> sense:$_ -> score:$h{$k}{$_}" }
        keys %{$h{$k}} 
    }   
    keys %h; 

say for @res;
```

Output

```
feature:oper -> sense:prod -> score:0.8
feature:move -> sense:prod -> score:0.6
feature:disp -> sense:prod -> score:0.2
feature:disp -> sense:phone -> score:0.05
feature:oper -> sense:phone -> score:0.03
feature:move -> sense:phone -> score:0.01
```

I set `phone` values to be less than `prod`'s to mimic posted data (irrelevant for processing).

The example hash `%h` stands for `%rankedTest` in the question. It may have either or both (or none) of `prod` and `phone` in subhashes.

Comment: hey zdim i like your answer but in my case, `feature:move -> sense:prod -> score:0.6` or `feature:move -> sense:phone -> score:0.6` but i will not have both at the same time.

Comment: @kero  That's fine.  The code will work with those that are there.  The `%h` above stands for your `%rankedTest`.  (I'll add a comment for this)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you're sorting the elements of the wrong hash. Your data structure `%rankedTest` looks like this

```perl
my %rankedTest = (
    operations => { product => 0.0859904478555225 },
    move       => { product => 0.309133999169732 },
    dispute    => { product => 0.0963311089384321 },
);
```

and you're sorting the keys of the inner hashes that look like `{ product => 0.0859904478555225 }`. But there's only a single element in each of them so your inner `for` loop executes only once and sorting makes no difference

Here I've sorted the outer hash by the value of the `product` element of the inner hash

Note that it's often simpler to save intermediate results into temporary variables when dealing with complex data structures. Here I've stored the sorted keys in array `@features` and the value of the score in `$score` to save putting the long hash expression into the `print` statement

```perl
my @features = sort {
    $rankedTest{$b}{product} <=> $rankedTest{$a}{product}
} keys %rankedTest;

for my $feature ( @features ) {

    my $score = $rankedTest{$feature}{product};

    print "feature:$feature -> sense:product -> score:$score\n";
}
```

#### output

```
feature:move -> sense:product -> score:0.309133999169732
feature:dispute -> sense:product -> score:0.0963311089384321
feature:operations -> sense:product -> score:0.0859904478555225
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but $rankedTest{$b}{product} is not always true , sometimes it could be $rankedTest{$b}{phone}

Comment: @kero: Okay. But what happens if there is both a `product` and a `phone` key?

Comment: i want to whoever with bigger value to come first

Comment: but i don't think that both will be a key for the same feature ,look  at foreach loop at the beginning that compare whoever has the bigger value and then assigned to the feature.